# $BSE = $BSECollection[$BSEindex - 1]; ErrorException Undefined offset: -1 Laravel

Tags: excel, vba, laravel, phpexcel

I am having this error whenever I'm exporting excel with macro(template) in Laravel 5.8

[image]

Here is the code I have:

```
$path = storage_path('template/latest/template.xls');

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(1)
    ->setCellValue('F4', $year . ' 年')
    ->setCellValue('G4', $month);

$filename = "請求管理表-" . $year . ' ' . $month . ".xls";

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("php://output");
```

Comment: The line causing the error isn't in the screenshot you've provided. Please can you also show the code that you have that is causing the issue.

Comment: hi, i have updated the image

Comment: Thanks. Please can you also copy and paste the code that **you** have that is causing the issue. Going off the stack trace I'd assume it's in your `BillingExportClaim` class.

Comment: i added code. thanks....

Comment: What version of PHPExcel are you using?

Comment: i'm using the old and tried using the new... but when i use the new i have new error



$path = storage_path('template/latest/template.xls');
        $spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($path);
        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    
        $filename = "請求管理表.xls";       
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        $writer->save("php://output");

Comment: Ah ok. Still, what version (exactly) are you using?

Comment: i'm using 1.8.2 from this https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel

Comment: the template.xls that i'm using is also a macro excel

Comment: This is a known issue with PHPExcel: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/commit/b964788d5c55f9c08a2320579d33a809bfa6c1f2. This should be fixed in version 1.11. If this version if working for you either then it might be worth looking at https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: still not working with 1.11...

Comment: I would suggest looking at https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ then as PHPExcel isn't maintained at all anymore.

Comment: if i use the phpsreadsheet, this is the error
iconv(): Detected an incomplete multibyte character in input string

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/494